# Create dynamic div classes in jade

Tags: angularjs, pug

What I need is to create classes dynamically using Jade and AngularJS.

For example, I have this "Hello World" code and I want to type in the class inside the text input (e.g. "alert alert-danger") and then change the appearance of the text in `{{first.greeting}} {{"World"}}` .

This means that I want this :

```
    input(type='text', ng-model='first.greeting')
    br
      .first.greeting
        {{first.greeting}} {{"World"}}
```

To be somehow rendered to this :

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="first.greeting">
    <br>
      <div class="">
        {{first.greeting}} {{"World"}}
      </div>
```

And the value of the class to be dynamically set.
How is that possible?

Comment: .(class='{{first.greeting}}')

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it returns an "unexpected token "dot" " message.

Comment: without dot. Just use (ng-class='{{first.greeting}}')

Comment: I have also tried that and it doesn't work. It returns " unexpected token "attrs" ". I think that the problem is that first.greeting is not initialized.

Comment: You need to use div(ng-class='{{first.greeting}}')

Comment: We have exactly the same way of thinking :) I have also tried this before. Now it renders to this:
        <input type="text" ng-model="first.greeting"><div ng-class="{{first.greeting}}"></div>{{first.greeting}} {{"World"}}. It does not change the class dynamically but sets the value {{first.greeting}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a javaScript expression, we need to wrap it using `()` like:

```
div(class='{{first.greeting}}')
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but It does not work this way, it sets a static value to the class and when I type nothing changes.

Comment: Just a sec.. Am creating a sample project to try it out :)

Comment: It should be  class='{{first.greeting}}' just now tried and its working